# Condition for Maximum Power in the circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

Maximum Power is transferred to a load when load resistance is equal to internal resistance of source.
I want to know How ?

If I consider a source with internal resistance 'R' ,connected with resistance 'R' and current through circuit is 'i'. Then power is P1=$ (i^2)$2R.
But if this source is connected to resistance 5R i.e internal resistance not equal to external resistance then Power P2= $(i^2)$6R, which is greater than P1. Then how the given statement above is true.

Comment: Bit of advice: Don't use the `?` punctuation unnecessarily like `???` ; also, this is a MathJax-enabled site; you can use the facility to format your equations; check this Meta Math.SE [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for a quick review of MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

If the voltage of the source is $V$ then the current $i= \dfrac{V}{R+r}$ where $r$ is the source resistance and $R$ is the load resistance.

So the power dissipated in the load resistance $R$ is $\dfrac{V^2}{(R+r)^2}R$.

Your error is to assume that the current $i$ does not change and try to evaluate the power dissipated in both resistors.

Substituting $r=R$ and $r=\dfrac R5$ will show you that the $r=R$ situation dissipates more power in the load resistor $R$ than when $r=\dfrac R5$.